# Sum, Subtract and Multiply arrays

Tags: c#

I've got the following arrays:

```cs
int[,] myArray1 = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 6, 8 } };
int[,] myArray2 = new int[2, 3] { { 6, 4, 3 }, { 8, 2, 8 } };
```

What I'd like to know how to do is:

1. **Create a new array with the sum of myArray1 and myArray2**
2. **Create a new array with the subtraction of myArray1 and myArray2**
3. **Create a new array with the multiplication of myArray1 and myArray2**

Result of sum would be:

```cs
int[,] myArray3 = new int[2, 3] { { 7, 6, 0 }, { -4, 4, 0 } };
```

Result of subtraction would be:

```cs
int[,] myArray3 = new int[2, 3] { { 5, 2, 6 }, { 12, 8, 16 } };
```

Result of multiplication would be:

```cs
int[,] myArray3 = new int[2, 3] { { 6, 8, 9 }, { 32, 12, 64 } };
```

Can this be done similar to printing out the arrays, with for loops? I tried looking for examples but found none that I could use for my specific problem.

Comment: What,A Homework Question

Comment: You just need to make a loop and sum/sub/mul all elements

Comment: Show your attempt with _for_ _loop_..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[,] a3 = new int[2,3];

for(int i = 0; i < myArray1.GetLength(0); i++)
{
for(int j = 0; j < myArray1.GetLength(1); j++)
{
a3[i,j] = myArray1[i,j] + myArray2[i,j];
a3[i,j] = myArray1[i,j] - myArray2[i,j];
a3[i,j] = myArray1[i,j] * myArray2[i,j];
}
}
```

need to store a3 before doing a new calculation obviously

Answer (score 3):

For **Sum**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                myArray3[i, j] = myArray1[i, j] + myArray2[i, j];
            }                
        }
```

For **Subtraction**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                myArray3[i, j] = myArray2[i, j] - myArray1[i, j];
            }                
        }
```

For **Multiplication**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                myArray3[i, j] = A[i, j] * B[i, j];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this would be done exactly like printing out the arrays with for loops

c# has foreach loops which would be even easier to use

Note: I get the idea this is for homework so I'm not going to give a 100% conclusive end all be all answer.

```
 int[,] myArray1 = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 6, 8 } };
 int[,] myArray2 = new int[2, 3] { { 6, 4, 3 }, { 8, 2, 8 } };
    
          foreach (int[] a1 in myArray1) 
          {
             foreach(int i in a1)
             {
                //operation here
                //you get the idea
             }        
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do array manipulation **faster** use the **C# Parallel.For** loop from **System.Threading.Tasks**:

For simple arithmetic parallelizing the outer loop is much faster than not on a modern PC processor. For more complex operations, or for small array sizes, the parallel version can be slower for various reasons.

Thus, use a stopwatch to time your matrix operations, and use the fastest solution. Parallelization makes doing array / **image processing in C#** much faster if implemented right.

Beware of overflowing your datatypes after arithmetic operations and also sharing variables between multiple threads (see **System.Threading.Interlocked** for help with that)...

Subtraction below. Similar for addition and multiplication:

```
Parallel.For(0, array.GetLength(1), y=>
{
    for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            difference[x,y] = minuend[x,y] - subtrahend[x,y];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a for loop, you can iterate through the rows/columns of the multi-d array as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray1.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray1.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        // Here, you can access the array data by index, using i and j. 
        // Ex, myArray1[i, j] will give you the value of 1 in the first iteration.
    }
}
```

Note: When you pass a value into the Array's GetLength method, it represents the dimension of the array. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx